# Examining function return value in GDB

Tags: gdb, debugging

If I break in line 3:

```
1  int foo()
2  {
3      return func();
4  }
```

is there a way to examine the return value of func()?

Thanks.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267674/inspect-the-return-value-of-a-function-in-gdb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inspect the return value of a function in gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267674/inspect-the-return-value-of-a-function-in-gdb)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`finish`](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_6.html#SEC37) command.

Answer (score 4):

After line three the return value will be in EAX, so you can

```
print $eax
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's true only on i386/amd64.

Answer (score 3):

If you step into "func()", and then say "finish", gdb will return 
to foo and print the return value of func.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a simular question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267674/inspect-the-return-value-of-a-function-in-gdb), info frame is a platform independent way todo this.