# How can I trace/catch "Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close" in valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind, file-descriptor

`valgrind` shows me the following:

```
==13880== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
```

Is there an easy way to investigate this error? I mean - to show stack-trace for example?

<sub>It's a huge project, I can't manually check each `close`. Also, I guess this would be the same for each sys call on bad filed descriptor.</sub>

---

I run it like:

```
valgrind --trace-children=yes --track-fds=yes --log-fd=2 --error-limit=no \
         --leak-check=full --show-possibly-lost=yes --track-origins=yes \
         --show-reachable=yes ./exe
```

the `exe` is with debug information.

A bigger piece of the `valgrind`'s output is:

```
==13880== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13880==    at 0x5A4022F: ??? (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==13880==    by 0x5A57323: ??? (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==13880==    by 0x5A56EC2: ??? (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==13880==    by 0x5A5555B: localtime_r (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==13880==    by 0x754E983: ??? (in /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.2)
==13880==    by 0x754EAC9: apr_time_exp_lt (in /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.2)
==13880==    by 0x6056B56: log4cxx::helpers::TimeZoneImpl::LocalTimeZone::explode(apr_time_exp_t*, long long) const (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880==    by 0x6037940: log4cxx::helpers::SimpleDateFormat::format(std::string&, long long, log4cxx::helpers::Pool&) const (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880==    by 0x5FBE539: log4cxx::pattern::CachedDateFormat::format(std::string&, long long, log4cxx::helpers::Pool&) const (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880==    by 0x5FCEA2B: log4cxx::pattern::DatePatternConverter::format(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::spi::LoggingEvent> const&, std::string&, log4cxx::helpers::Pool&) const (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880==    by 0x601EE10: log4cxx::PatternLayout::format(std::string&, log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::spi::LoggingEvent> const&, log4cxx::helpers::Pool&) const (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880==    by 0x605BCAB: log4cxx::WriterAppender::subAppend(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::spi::LoggingEvent> const&, log4cxx::helpers::Pool&) (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==13880==    at 0x40255BC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==13880==    by 0x5A57A03: ??? (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==13880==    by 0x5A56D17: ??? (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==13880==    by 0x5A56E20: ??? (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==13880==    by 0x5A5555B: localtime_r (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==13880==    by 0x754E983: ??? (in /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.2)
==13880==    by 0x754EAC9: apr_time_exp_lt (in /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.2)
==13880==    by 0x605701D: log4cxx::helpers::TimeZoneImpl::LocalTimeZone::getTimeZoneName() (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880==    by 0x6055D53: log4cxx::helpers::TimeZone::getDefault() (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880==    by 0x6038606: log4cxx::helpers::SimpleDateFormat::SimpleDateFormat(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880==    by 0x5FCF09D: log4cxx::pattern::DatePatternConverter::getDateFormat(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&) (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880==    by 0x5FCF587: log4cxx::pattern::DatePatternConverter::DatePatternConverter(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&) (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==13880== 
==13880== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
```

The empty line before the `Warning` makes me think the stacktrace above is NOT relevant to the warning. Also, after the `Warning` comes the `Summary`, nothing else.

Comment: Valgrind usually shows a stack trace if it can. Are you running an unstripped program, built with debugging symbols?

Comment: @MikeSeymour - I edited my question, adding more information (which I think is irrelevant, but still)

Comment: As far as I know Valgrind does not give stack trace for `Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()`. But perhaps I only never found the switch to turn it on ... :-}

Comment: @alk - yep, it looks like this, I wonder why.

Comment: At least if on Linux you'd be on the safe side ignoring this warning. However, the main thing to learn from this it to **also always check the outcome** of the `close()` system call and to log it.

Comment: @alk - I completely agree with you, but the code isn't written only by me ((un)fortunatelly :))

Comment: For me, I got this when I had a UDP socket that was closed, but had never been opened.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Running valgrind (ver.3) with -v produces also for invalid file descriptor
warnings a stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way seems to be: put a breakpoint in `close()`. This of course assumes you can run your program in a debugger, but if you can run it in Valgrind that doesn't seem very far-fetched.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I put a breakpoint in `::close`? I can't put breakpoint on a forward declaration( `extern int close (int __fd);` in `unistd.h`), right?

Comment: Aha! I found out - I can use `catch syscall close` but do you have any idea how to see the return of the syscall?

Comment: @KirilKirov: Do `b close` to set the breakpoint on `close()`, then `r` to run the program and if stopped at the breakpoint step in the syscall by doing `s`, then do a `fin` and gdb shows you the return value of the call.

Comment: @alk - `fin` doesn't show me the return value. I just made a small test app, just to check this. `gdb` shows me things like `(gdb) fin [\n]
Run till exit from #0  0x08048586 in f() () [\n]
0x08048590 in main ()`, where `f` returns an `int` inside and I don't see the returned value.

Comment: @KirilKirov: You might like to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/267674/694576

Comment: @alk - yep, I tried a similar thing, but it didn't work, because ... I forgot to add the `-g` while compiling the test app.. Thanks!

Comment: @KirilKirov: So to have this work with `close()` you need to link against a version of the (g)libc compiled with `-g `, a debug version most probably.

Comment: @alk - yep, I figured it out. Thanks for the help.